# What is the name of C(OOOH)₄?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I've been practicing organic nomenclature and I was wondering if anyone could show me the proper way to approach naming this molecule. My guess would be methane-quadra-dioxyanol.

[image: 1,1',1'',1'''-methanetetrayltetrakis(trioxidane)]

Comment: I would call it boomane, since if you attempted to synthesize it something would probably go boom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This molecule doesn't have any carbon to hydrogen bonds, so it likely wouldn't even be properly named using organic nomenclature. Tetrachloromethane, for example, is correctly named [carbon tetrachloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_tetrachloride). If you wanted to throw technicalities to the wind, however, along with the fact that this compound would likely be so incredibly unstable that no one would even bother attempting to synthesize and isolate it, it would probably be named tetratrioxidanylmethane.

You might notice the name bears some similarities to tetrachloromethane. That's because it's four of the same group, the trioxidanyl group (from [trioxidane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trioxidane)), bonded to a single carbon.

Answer (score 4):

Under [this entry](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/118203806#section=Top), PubChem hosts even a $\ce{CH4O22}$ with an surprisingly systematic name (after all) of "bis(hydroperoxyperoxyperoxyperoxy)-bis(trioxidanyl)methane"

[image]

So far, however, experimentally determined properties are still to add to this entry created on February 23rd, 2016.  And the absence of a CAS registry number suggests (maybe for the better) that this maybe high-energy material was not not yet isolated.

Comment: I think, it’s surprisingly unsystematic. I would have expected a more systematic name labelling the longer oxygen chain as a chain similar to the all-carbon compound. But $+1$ for the finding!

Answer (score 4):

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*), the preselected name for the compound $\ce{HO-O-OH}$ is **trioxidane.** According to rule P-68.4.1.1, such compounds with three or more contiguous identical chalcogen atoms are treated as parent structures. For example, the preferred IUPAC name of the compound $\ce{CH3OOOCH3}$ is dimethyltrioxidane (note that the locants of 1,3-dimethyltrioxidane are omitted in the preferred IUPAC name).

Therefore, the parent structure for the preferred IUPAC name of the compound that is given in the question should be trioxidane and not methane. However, this compound contains four individual trioxidane structures. In order to name such assemblies of two or more identical parent structures that are linked by a bi- or multivalent substituent group, multiplicative nomenclature can be used (e.g. 1,1'-peroxydibenzene). In this case, four trioxidane parent structures (“tetrakis(trioxidane)”) are linked by a tetravalent methanetetrayl substituent, which leads to the preferred IUPAC name **1,1',1'',1'''-methanetetrayltetrakis(trioxidane).**